# Extract Hyperlink from a spool pdf file in Python

Tags: fastapi

I am getting my form data from frontend and reading it using fast api as shown below:

```
@app.post("/file_upload")
async def upload_file(pdf: UploadFile = File(...)):
    print("Content = ",pdf.content_type,pdf.filename,pdf.spool_max_size)
    return {"filename": "Succcess"}
```

Now what I need to do is extract hyperlinks from these spool Files with the help of `pypdfextractor` as shown below:

```
import pdfx
from os.path import exists
from config import availableUris
def getHrefsFromPDF(pdfPath:str)->dict:
    if not(exists(pdfPath)):
        raise FileNotFoundError("PDF File not Found")
    pdf = pdfx.PDFx(pdfPath)
    return pdf.get_references_as_dict().get('url',[])
```

But I am not sure how to convert spool file (Received from FAST API) to pdfx readable file format.

Additionally, I also tried to study the bytes that come out of the file. When I try to do this:

`data = await pdf.read()`

data type shows as : `bytes` when I try to convert it using `str` function it gives a unicoded encoded string which is totally a gibberish to me, I also tried to decode using "utf-8" which throws UnicodeDecodeError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fastapi gives you a [`SpooledTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile). You may be able to use that file object directly if there is some api in pdfx which will work on a `File()` object rather than a str representing a path (!).  Otherwise make a new temporary file on disk and work with that:

```py
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory
from pathlib import Path
import pdfx

@app.post("/file_upload")
async def upload_file(pdf: UploadFile = File(...)):
    with TemporaryDirectory() as d: #Adding the file into a temporary storage for re-reading purposes
        tmpf = Path(d) / "pdf.pdf"
        with tmpf.open("wb") as f:
            f.write(pdf.read())

        p = pdfx.PDFX(str(tmpf))
        ...
```

It may be that `pdfx.PDFX` will take a `Path` object.  I'll update this answer if so.  I've kept the read-write loop synchronous for ease, but you can make it asynchronous if there is a reason to do so.

Note that it would be better to find a way of doing this with the `SpooledTemporaryFile`.

As to your data showing as bytes: well, pdfs are (basically) binary files: what did you expect?

Comment: Yeah I agree... I got it working by the way you told. But I also prefer to find a way doing it with SpooledTemporaryFile. I am not sure if pdfx could get it done directly or not

Comment: @ShivamSahil sadly looking at the [source](https://github.com/metachris/pdfx/blob/master/pdfx/__init__.py#L97) this is not possible.  You could refactor this to take e.g. an optional `stream` param, make the `uri` param optional, and then add a check for one or the other (and maybe a check for `hasattr(.read()` on the stream.  Would make a nice little PR if they wanted it, and would handle this kind of use case.

Comment: Hmm makes sense... Yeah would try doing that, thanks anyways

Comment: Btw which version of python are you using @2e0byo. I am getting some errors from your code. Adding another edit

Comment: Apologies, I had forgotten that `TemporaryDirectory` returns a *str*, not *path*